# What is wrong with my Watcher (incron-like) daemon?

Tags: linux, security, monitoring, incrond

I have installed [Watcher](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2011-01/07-watcher_a_recursive_incron_alternative) this way: both `watcher.py` and `watcher.ini` are located in `/etc`
I also installed `pyinotify` and it does work when I use `python -m pyinotify -v /var/www`

However, I want to use the daemon and when I start `watcher.py`, I get weird lines on my `watcher.log` (see below).
I also included my `watcher.ini` file.

Note: I have the latest version of Python. The watcher.py can be found [here](https://github.com/greggoryhz/Watcher/blob/master/watcher.py)

What is wrong with what I did? Also, do I really need pyinotify?
Thanks a lot for your help

*watcher.ini:*

```
[DEFAULT]
logfile=/var/log/watcher.log
pidfile=/var/run/watcher.pid

[job1]
watch=/var/www
events=create,delete,modify
recursive=true
command=mkdir /home/mockfolder ## just using this as test
```

*watcher.log:*

```
2012-09-22 04:28:23.822029 Daemon started
2012-09-22 04:28:23.822596 job1: /var/www
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/watcher.py", line 359, in <module>
    daemon.start()
  File "/etc/watcher.py", line 124, in start
    self.run()
  File "/etc/watcher.py", line 256, in run
    autoadd   = self.config.getboolean(section,'autoadd')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 368, in getboolean
    v = self.get(section, option)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 618, in get
    raise NoOptionError(option, section)
ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'autoadd' in section: 'job1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'autoadd' in section: 'job1'
```

As far as I know, `autoadd` option is required. You can set it to false if you don't want to watch the new subdirectory:

```
; if true, watcher will automatically watch new subdirectory
autoadd=false
```

**`/tmp/watcher.log`**:

```
2012-09-23 22:30:33.934975 Daemon started
2012-09-23 22:30:33.935313 job1: /tmp
```

**`ps -ef | grep [w]atcher`**

`quanta   19813     1  0 22:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2.7 ./watcher.py start --config watcher.ini`

Comment: quanta, thanks so much for this, you made my day! Regards